# ruby run local server key error key not found se_bucket_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

So I am working on a already created ruby app.

The contractor we hired is taking too long to finish the job so I because of this, I am coming into this app not knowing somethings about it's setup.

when I run the local server I get the  follow:

```
C:\Users\chris\Documents\suitsandtables>ruby bin\rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
```

I usually develop in linux but switched to windows for quick setup of rails and  ruby so I am also not too familiar with developing on windows.

when I try to connect to the localhost I get a refusal to connect.

Im trying to figure out if its this s3 bucket thing thats messing everything up.

the s3.rb file looks like this:

```
Rails.application.config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
        bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
        access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the AWS-S3 configuration information, if you have access to the aws(Amazon web services) account, then create an API key and add it as an environment variable, or create a local_env file, with each key and value

Heres is more details on how to set env variables
https://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html